# How to save values of JSON String iinto Android internal SQLite database using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to Volley and liking it so far because it seems simple to make a HTTP call even if you are in the main thread / OnCreate class.

So far I am having success retrieving the JSON String from the endpoint and can display the first few characters in my TextBox.  Now I want to save it to my internal NoSQL DB in my android app. My problem is I am clueless on how to directly save this JSON String into my android app's SQLite DB.  Does Volley have a direct method for this?  My Table only has 2 fields and will only need to fetch the two key-value pairs in the JSON.

Below is what I have working so far.
I am not even sure if the part **DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI** is the right thing to do but so far it is working.

```
btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/api/wordsupdate.php";

                // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                //StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(DownloadManager.Request.Method.GET, url,
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // Display the first characters of the response string.
                                txt_output.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 100));
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        txt_output.setText("That didn't work!");
                    }
                });
                // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                //queue.add(stringRequest);
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
```

Below is the JSON from the endpoint

```
[{"id":"1","param1":"word1","param2":"word1Equivalent","version":"1"},{"id":"2","param1":"word2","param2":"word2Equivalent","version":"1"},{"id":"3","param1":"word3","param2":"word3Equivalent","version":"1"}]
```

Comment: Sorry I will correct my question I am using SQLite not NoSQL

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `JSONObject` into `String` and save. While retrieving the same column convert the `String` into `JSONObject`.

Below is the example,

```
String stringToBeSaved = jsonObject.toString(); (can be save to DB as text or varchar)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to get the key value pairs inside the json and insert them to their appropriate SQLite columns

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265800/reading-data-from-json-and-saving-it-in-android-app-using-ormlite.